# Jenkins Windows Execute Command Line BitVise sexec Fails with exit 1000 at the end

Tags: windows, shell, jenkins

I am just setting up a new Jenkins system on Windows server 2016.

One of my build steps is to execute a batch file that I have been using with FinalBuilder.

This batch file creates a 7z backup of my existing web site before over writing it.

Here is my command in Jenkins (some parameters obviously changed for privacy in this post):

```
sexec myuser@myserver.cloudapp.net -pw=mypassword -cmd="bvBackup C:\inetpub\SiteName SiteName"
```

Here is bvBackup.bat contents:

```
cd %1
for /f "tokens=2-8 delims=.:/ " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do set DateNtime=%%c-%%a-%%b_%%d-%%e-%%f
7z a -r ..\%2Backup\%2_%DateNtime% *.*
```

Basically it just zips the files up into an archive with the current date and time in the name.

Here are the last few lines of the output from the Jenkins console:

```
12:14:42 Compressing  site\bin\UserAuthorization.dll
12:14:42 Compressing  site\bin\WebGrease.dll
12:14:42 Compressing  site\bin\zlib1.dll
12:14:42 
12:14:42 Everything is Ok
12:14:42 
12:14:42 D:\Jenkins\workspace\MyProjectName - Staging>exit 1000 
12:14:42 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
12:14:42 Finished: FAILURE
```

What I am trying to figure out is where the exit 100 is coming from. That is not part of my batch file. 7zip is saying everything is Ok.

The path on D: is the jenkins working folder path. Everything else is from our staging server where the compressing is happening over sexec ssh shell.

Why is this failing when the output from the work seems to be fine? Where is the exit 1000 coming from?

**Update:** Turns out the exit 1000 is coming from the sexec and is normal. I have tried several things in my batch file that is getting executed to deal with it, but Jenkins always assumes it is a bad state and fails the build.

Can someone tell me how to tell Jenkins that exit 1000 is success when using Windows Batch Execution?

Comment: Turns out this problem isn't just with the 7zip command line. All of the commands that I issue using the execute windows batch are ending with exit 1000 even though everything seems to go fine. The only thing that is common is that I am using sexec and executing them on a remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a way to make this work.

I changed my direct execution of the sexec in jenkins to be a call to a batch file from Jenkins.

Then in the batch file I have the code:

```
sexec -cmd=%1
if errorlevel 1000 goto success
goto end
:success
EXIT 0
:end
```

That sets the errorlevel to 0 when sexec returns 1000